# Journal of Fluid Mechanics Class Constraints

Tags: floats, formatting, captions

I am trying to format a paper to be consistent with the JFM style guidelines. I am using the JFM Latex class provided on the [website](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displaySpecialPage?pageId=2860). However, this class appears to be forcing a format that is not consistent with the JFM standards. For example,

1. Figure captions that are more than one line should be left-justified. I cannot figure out how to override the setting in the class that is currently center-justifying all figure captions, regardless of length.
2. Figures should appear at the top or bottom of a page, as soon as possible after they are referenced. The class setting is forcing all figures to be at the top of a page, and these figures currently appear BEFORE they are referenced in the text. However, I haven't been able to override this setting. I have tried the standard `\begin{figure}[b]` command.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problems you're experiencing. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just type your submission using the template and following the instructions. It's *their* job to make the final printout to comply with *their* standards.

Comment: The class says `\def\fps@figure{tp}`, so `\begin{figure}` will choose `t` or `p` placement. There is a `bottomfigure` environment for bottom placement, but not a corresponding `bottomtable` environment.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, you can try use the `caption` package and write in your preamble:

```
\captionsetup{format=plain,justification=justified}
```

Another valid option `would be`format=hang`. You also can set the width of the caption with`\captionsetup{width=…}`. See the details in §2 of the documentation.

If you want your caption to be no wider than the figure, you can put it in a `measuredfigure` environment, from the `threeparttable` package,  in the following manner:

```
\begin{figure}{!h}
\centering
\begin{measuredfigure}
\includegraphics{…}
\caption{…}
\label{…}
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{figure}
```

This environment measures the width of element it encoses (figure or table) and puts it in a minipage.

For the second point, perhaps try the `H`specifier (from the `float` package): the figure will stop floating, or load the `flafter` package.

Comment: About the second requirement, why not use the `flafter` package instead of completely preventing floats?

Comment: Not mentioned it because I never used it,  but you're right: I'll add it to my answer.